# Including <Windows.h> causes (unknown attribute"no_init_all") error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, header

Title says it all, started a new project in VS2017, included `<iostream>`, then when I went to include `<Windows.h>` (This is my first attempt at working with this header by the way), I got the error saying: `unknown attribute"no_init_all"`
Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: @S.M. Hi,I already tried Google,I wasn't able to find this specific issue,note that I mentioned that I've never worked with this header file before,I also never encountered/expected a case where the error comes from a standard library header,so please,if you don't know a solution,which you clearly don't,considering you haven't provided one already,I kindly ask from you to remove that down-vote,so that someone more helpful may see my problem,and help me solve it.

Comment: The first reference in Google solves this intellisense warning

Comment: I was hoping for another solution aside from installing VS2019,but thank you for your feedback.

Comment: It is related to Windows SDK update, not Visual Studio version. The first link in Google is [VS 2017 (15.9.2) reports "unknown attribute "no_init_all" only in Intellisense](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/387702/vs-2017-1592-reports-unknown-attribute-no-init-all.html)

Comment: The link provided in the Microsoft Solution comment takes you to the VS2019 download page,and a reply to that comment does confirm that "This fix is only in Visual Studio 2019 and will not be backported to 2017." And I can confirm that seems to be the case,as the problem has been resolved once I re-opened the project inVS2019 (I honestly don't know if I had the latest SDK update,but migrating to VS2019 did seem to solve this problem,among other things,so thank you!)

Comment: Yep, only fixed in 2019! But this worked for me: "#define no_init_all deprecated" or even "#define no_init_all" https://stackoverflow.com/a/62552206/313445

Comment: @NickWestgate that comment should be an answer, since it works.

Comment: @EdBayiates Good point. Too many comments. Done! : - )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, putting those comments into an answer ...

This bug is fixed in [VS 2019](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/387702/vs-2017-1592-reports-unknown-attribute-no-init-all.html), but as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62552206/313445), in VS 2017 you can use:

```
#define no_init_all deprecated
```

or even just:

```
#define no_init_all
```

Comment: It does appear to depend on the toolset.
Earlier toolsets (e.g. 10.0.17134.0) don't have this problem.
10.0.19041.0 definitely does.